# aws cli : s3api append lifecycle policy to existing ones

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have multiple lifecycle policies for a bucket, whenever I try to create a new one, I have to manually do the following things:

**STEP 1:**

Run:

```
aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration  --bucket my-bucket > lifecycle.json
```

**STEP 2:**
then edit the **lifecycle.json** and append the new policy

**STEP 3:**

Run:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket <bucket_name> --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json
```

otherwise, it will replace the old policies.

Is there any way to directly append the new policy with the existing ones?

For Example:

My Existing policies:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 365
            },
            "ID": "Policy 1",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "dir1/dir2/code/"
            },
            "Status": "Enabled"
        },
        {
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 90
            },
            "ID": "Policy 2",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "Name/Address/code/"
            },
            "Status": "Enabled"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add this policy:

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Days": 20
      },
      "ID": "TEST_POLICY_09082021_ARANI2",
      "Filter": {
        "Prefix": "backup/ARANI2/files/"
      },
      "Status": "Enabled"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use `jq` to append to your json.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I am new to jq can you please tell me the way to append a specific rule?

Comment: Sadly, I can't as you haven't provided any example of such a json, nor how you want to change it.

Comment: Hi Marcin, I have updated the question for your help